# Mex C++ Class Function Declaration

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have to write c++ code that takes in a few matrices from MatLab, analyzes those matrices, and outputs a single matrix. The code for the analyzing is already written and all of the matrices and variables are declared in a class lets call it class MMclass

```
class MMclass {

  public:   

    // Start point of the application
    int inici(void);        

    #ifdef _WIN32
        ...
    #elif linux
        ...
    #endif

  private:          

    // Variables -------------------------------------------

    // Private methods -------------------------------------------
    ...
    void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]);
    ...
};
```

Most of the code is already written and I am simply attempting to add the `mexFunction to increase the efficiency`. Because of this, I want to be able to use

```
void MMclass::mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    ...
}
```

to access and modify the variables declared in the original class that is also used by the rest of the code. I cant figure out how to declare the mexFunction in the MMclass to allow for it to work. The mexFuntion is found in read.cpp and I am using mex read.cpp to compile. I have tried to instead use a struct and pass that struct but it is quite tedious to change all of the prewritten code.

Comment: It's not clear how you are planning to use the library and instantiate the class, but MATLAB looks for a single entry point: the global namespace function `mexFunction` exported from the library.  Just because `MMclass` has a method named `mexFunction` doesn't make it accessible.  Do you need persistent memory?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: There is a previously declared class called MMclass and that class and its variables are used in the rest of the code. I want the mexFunction entry point to take in values from MatLab and change the values of those variables in MMclass accordingly. I have managed to extract each matrix individually and have the exact format. All I need is to be able to copy over those variables from mexFunction to the class so the rest of the program can use those variables.

Comment: You still haven't explained how you plan for an instance of this class to come into being. If there's another process (i.e. an executable besides MATLAB that is running and has this class), you can't inject data into a different process like this. If you want to use this class then write a `mexFunction` that creates this class and add a method to manipulate it's member variables.

Comment: How would I create the class within the mexFunction? That is exactly what I'm trying to do as there is an executable using this class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MMclass {

  public:   

    // Start point of the application
    int inici(void);        

    #ifdef _WIN32
        ...
    #elif linux
        ...
    #endif

  private:          

    // Variables -------------------------------------------

    // Private methods -------------------------------------------
     ...

    ...
};

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  MMclass YourClassInstance;

}
```